# Sync Apache Root Folder on Two Ubuntu Servers

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

We currently have two AWS ubuntu instance running two websites on Apache. The instances are behind a load balance. I would like to know what would be the best way to sync the root folder for both servers. I would like to so a two-way sync. Right now when I have to change a file or to do an update, I have to login to both server and do exactly the same thing o both, so I would like to set something up so, no matter what server I update or change the files will be updated on the other server. I though on using Rsync but I read that it is not meant to do two-ways sync. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? I have to say, it's likely well worth the engineering effort for you to not have to do this, as it's error-prone and clumsy. Instead, put user uploads or other files that change frequently in S3.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I first want to check what would be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

you could try unison. It must be triggered after changing a file, but you can use a regular cronjob for it.
After initialisation it recognises changed/added/deleted files and updates this information on the other server.

Comment: Can unison run on different servers and does it syncs files both ways? If I use a cron job would that be on only one server or on both servers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for instantaneous update of content, anything you run will need a service that stays in contact with configured peers. This requires monitoring and management.

Having been down this road before, I'd suggest setting up test environments and running website performance testing tools against any selected solution. Many of the solutions have significant drawbacks that require sizing and testing with a production workload to fully appreciate.

Comment: I am not looking for instantaneous update. A cron job running every 5 minutes will do. I am just not sure which way would be the best once those are two servers but on the same network.

Comment: 5 MINUTES? Sheesh. This is ABC stuff then. You could easily do this with a Git repo if you can live with 5 minutes of update latency.